# What would cause SSL Certificate errors across all installed OSX browsers but Firefox?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, ssl-certificate, fastly

Every attempt to connect to Wired.com is met with a certificate error.

[image: The Cert Error]

I've checked the usual suspects and even done things that probably have nothing to do with it.
Browsers tried

```
Safari=failed
Chrome=failed
Brave=failed
Firefox=success
```

- Verified no Chrome extensions interfering (incognito w/ no approved incog extensions)
- Same with Safari.
- Flushed DNS
- Rebooted
- Time settings obv correct

I started to get paranoid thinking that something is hijacking my connection, but the only active ports I've got open and connected are... well, supposed to be open. And then the fact that it works with Firefox is even stranger. Firefox is my proxy browser, but it works via proxy w/out.

This is a recently upgraded Sierra machine. I'm not an avid wired reader, so I couldn't tell you if it was happening previously, but I can say I've got 4 other mac test machines here and none of them are experiencing the same issue.

Sierra vs Capitan doesn't make a difference. And this is now going on a 2 week issue. Wired appears to be literally the only site effected. At this point it's more a curiosity at getting to the bottom of this than anything else, since it does appear to be something isolated to this machine.

Also, I think we can rule out a CDN issue. As all my other machines are connecting from this same wanIP.

Man, just absolutely any suggestions for more internals I could go digging through to try and get to the bottom of this would be oh so greatly appreciated. Because I've about relegated myself to keyboard head smashing.

Comment: Firefox does not use the system certificates, so that would explain the difference.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thank you so much, I bet if I nuke my keychain it will clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

The problem (most likely) is caused due to recent issue at GlobalSign as they incorrectly revoked their cross-certificates. Full statament from GlobalSign: [Certificate Revocation Issue](https://www.globalsign.com/en/customer-revocation-error/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. That GlobalSign certificate was cached.

Removing the cache at

/var/db/crls worked

I backed it up first just in case, but sudo wiping the cache didn't cause any problems.

> sudo rm /var/db/crls/crlcache*
>
> sudo rm /var/db/crls/ocspcache.db*